Dynamic Pivot Table, Pivot Table that can reference multiple Tables
If I have multiple Tables in a sheet, all with same columns and headers, how could I have 1 Pivot Table that allows me to reference the different Tables 1 at a time.  For example, it is pulling data from Table A for view in the Pivot Table.  But Then I use a drop down, check box or selection to change the reference Table from A to B.  The end state is 1 Pivot table that is able to dynamically change the reference data across multiple standard tables.

Define name tables and use INDIRECT() function for each source. Or using Power Query Connection. Look here

AS another option, you may just want to stack each table on top of eachother into a new long table and create a new column called "tablename" that holds the name of the table for that row. Then you can use "tablename" in your pivot filter drop down or slicer.

Agree to @JNevill Sir, there are many options these days, if using MS365, with newer functions it really makes flexible and scalable. Totally agree, i think this is the best instead of INDIRECT(), as INDIRECT() is volatile in nature, and slows down the functionality of Excel. Sorry I have suggested abt the volatile function, completely forgotten abt the usage of VSTACK(). Thanks sir for reminding again.

No reason to apologize @MayukhBhattacharya I think Indirect (while memory heavy) is good option if these tables are smaller. I would agree there are a lot of ways to solve these days. None of them are going to be very simple though.

Thank you both for the input, the tables are indeed going to be quite small.  Nothing super data heavy.  As for these options, do either of you have example documents I can reference so that I can reverse engineer the solutions?
